# Maven - Could not find artifact error on terminal, but Eclipse works

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've just downloaded this [Github project](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns) that contains the following `Pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  [...]
-->
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.iluwatar</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-design-patterns</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>model-view-controller</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The installed version of Maven is the following (`mvn -version`):

```
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T17:06:16+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.2/libexec
Java version: 12.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "Mac"
```

If I try to run `man validate` from command line I get the following error

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.iluwatar:model-view-controller:1.22.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.iluwatar:java-design-patterns:pom:1.22.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 29, column 11
```

But, if I try to run this out of Eclipse, everything works..

Why is this the case?

Are they using different `settings.xml`?

Debugging `mvn -X validate` on Eclipse outputs

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/myname/.m2/settings.xml
```

and debugging the call from the terminal outputs

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.2/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/myname/.m2/settings.xml
```

The `settings.xml` in Cellar has no entries, the one in `/Users/myname/.m2/settings.xml` does not exist, but I could not find the one used by Eclipse (I think the m2e-plugin).

Comment: From which directory are you running `mvn`: `model-view-controller` or `java-design-patterns`? You may need to run from the parent at least once to have it install that POM in your local repository. Maven on the command line doesn't "resolve projects from workspace"...

Comment: Ah, this is the problem, I am running `mvn` in the `model-view-controller` folder. So Eclipse can resolve the parent pom, but terminal not, am I right?

Comment: I believe that's what is going on. Just note that the goal to run in parent is `install` (or something that implies it)

Comment: Ah okay.. Very interesting. BIG thanks for your help!!
But what's strange: If I run `mvn install` in Eclipse for only the `model-view-controller` `pom` it only creates an entry for `model-view-controller` in my local repository.. Shouldn't it also create a folder for the parent `java-design-patterns`?

Comment: No. It doesn't work like that. What you build (the pom you call mvn with or the one in the working directory) is what gets installed (and its children if that happens to be a pom with modules). Builds run child poms, not parent poms.

Comment: Perfectly explained!! Thanks a lot!